# angularJS $compile is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and I'm trying to dynamically compile some DOM elements... 
I've tried the demo:

```
try {
        var templateHTML = angular.element('<p>{{total}}</p>'),
            scope = ....;

        var clonedElement = $compile(templateHTML)(scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {
          //attach the clone to DOM document at the right place
        });

        //now we have reference to the cloned DOM via `clone`
} catch (ex) {
alert(ex.message);
}
```

but all I get back is a "$compile is not defined"

HELP!

Comment: What does the rest of your controller look like, did you inject compile into the controller (e.g. controller('mycontroller', function($compile){...}).

Answer (score 8):

A sample code for using $compile in a directive. Basically go ahead & first append the element to DOM (might want to keep it invisible), then run the compile by using a finder.. as mentioned by rtcherry, $compile should be injected.

```
        //
        componentModule.directive('getCompilerWk', function($compile) {
          return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
              elm.click(function(){
                    $(body).append(templateHTML);
                    $compile($(body).find('p'))(scope);

              })
            }
          };
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

Where are you calling this code from?  Is it safe to assume it is outside of the Angular framework by your use of angular.element(...)?

If so, you can use this:

```
// Split across two lines for readability...
angular.element(<something within Angular's scope>)
    .injector().get('$compile')(...)
```

If not, you may simply need to inject $compile into the controller/directive/service.