# Using AngularJS with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, total.js

I have some AngularJS stuff that holds a bunch of arrays and data. Once a user uploads a file, the file gets parsed up and saved into the scope with its different arrays. However, after all of this and the file is held in the scope, I try to update the innerHTML, but the AngularJS code does not work. I use `ng-repeat` to create a table based on the arrays, but it remains a single cell with content looking like `{{column}}` and the like.

I have had extreme difficulty using directives and templates because my index.html says that `app` and `module`, etc, are undefined when I do something such as `app.directive(...`

The significant parts of my index.html file include:

```
<html ng-app>
... //once a file is uploaded, total.js is called;
//this was so the app didn't try to run before a file was uploaded
<div id="someStuff">This will become a table once a file is uploaded</div>
```

This is a simple example of how my scope is set up in total.js:

```
function sheet($rootScope, $parse){
    $rootScope.stuff = text; 
//text is a variable that contains the file's contents as a string
};

document.getElementById('someStuff').innerHTML="<div ng-controller='sheet'>{{stuff}}</div>";
```

The HTML changes but instead of printing the file's contents, it only prints `{{stuff}}`.
How can I get the innerHTML to understand that it contains AngularJS, preferably without using a partial or a directive, unless you can thoroughly explain where I'd input it and the syntax of it.

**Edit 1:**
I have tried using $compile but it is marked as undefined. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907106/angularjs-compile-is-not-defined) to figure out the compile problem, but I don't understand rtcherry's syntax, and how I should apply it to my own code.

**Edit 2:**
I still receive $compile undefined errors when I include it like so:

```
function sheet($rootScope, $parse, $compile){...};
document.getElementById('someStuff').innerHTML=$compile("<div ng-controller='sheet'>
{{stuff}}</div>")(scope);
```

**Edit 3:**
While itcouldevenbeaboat's comment was extremely unhelpful, I decided I should perhaps show you the directive way I attempted to do it.

I included this code under my sheet function:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.directive('spreadsheeet', function($compile){
    return{
        templateUrl: innerHTML.html
    }
});
```

Where innerHTML contains `<div ng-controller='sheet'>{{stuff}}</div>`and on index.html I've included `<div spreadsheet></div>`

With this, I receive no errors, but the text does not show up, neither as `{{stuff}}` or as the file's contents. Even when I do something simple, such as provide `template: "<h2>Hello!</h2>"` instead of a `templateUrl`, I cannot get `Hello!` to print.

Comment: innerHTML =$compile("<div ng-controller='sheet'>{{stuff}}</div>")(scope)

Comment: you can inject $compile like other angular services/tools. Just the same way as you would like use $scope or $rootScope.

Comment: I still receive errors. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: INCOMING BIG HELP: You should not use innerHTML with Angular.js. END BIG HELP

Answer (score 5):

It works for me

```
document.getElementById('someStuff').innerHTML = "<div ng-controller='sheet'>{{stuff}}</div>";
$compile( document.getElementById('someStuff') )($scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (it will work 100%):

In controller, **don't forget to inject  $document** in **controller** as a dependency, like this:

```
App.controller('indiaController', function ($scope, $document,$filter, $location) {

    var text_element = angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#delhi');
    text_element.html('your dynamic html placed here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ngBindHtml

- directive in module ng

Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core AngularJS). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application.

Usage

```
as element:
```

```
    <ng-bind-html
      ng-bind-html="expression">
    ...
    </ng-bind-html>
```

```
as attribute:
```

```
    <ANY
      ng-bind-html="expression">
    ...
    </ANY>
```